# Labels aren't showing before fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

This snippet is from forms.py:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    Specialist = forms.ModelChoiceField(label = 'Test', queryset = SpecialistModel.objects.all(), empty_label = None)
```

And this from template:

```
{{ form.Specialist }}
```

Field is showing and label is not. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show label manually:

```
{{ form.Specialist.label }}
```

or

```
{{ form.Specialist.label_tag }}
```

to show label wrapped in html `<label></label>` tag.